# How to I call this method?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I have this piece of code and I feel so dumb for not knowing how to run it. Please help.

```
class Solution(object):
    def countOdds(self, low: int, high: int):
        if low % 2 == 0 and high % 2 == 0:
            return (high-low)//2
        else:
            return (high-low)//2 + 1
```

I tried running `Solution.countOdds(3, 11)` but the error showed me that I haven't called *self*, and I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: You need to make an instance.  `print(Solution().countOdds(3,11))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object linking to the class and then call that.
So instead of doing Solution.countOdds(3, 11), you need to do

```
MyObject = Solution()
MyObject.countOdds(3, 11)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a method of the class but haven't created an instance. Try:

```
class Solution(object):...

instance = Solution()
print(instance.countOdds(3,11))
```